# How do I completely remove LazReport?

Tags: uninstall, lazarus

I have a standard user account in addition to the admin account on 12.04 Deskop.

I have Lazarus + LazReport component added to it.

Due to a bug I cannot trace, I'm trying to remove LazReport.

I tried using the standard feature of uninstalling and reinstalling LazReport using the IDE but I cannot get rid of the error. I think there is a trace of Lazreport even after it's removed.

My requirement: I want to completely remove every trace of LazReport (not Lazarus).

How do I do this?

Thanks!

EDIT: 
About LazReport...
It is a 'component' added onto the Lazarus IDE. On the IDE, I go to 'Package' > 'Open Package File' > Open the LazReport pacakge > 'Install'

Then after the installation, the IDE is rebuilt (automatically) and restarted. The same procedure is used to remove it. But I'm concerned if there are still traces of it.

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get --purge remove lazreport` ??

Comment: 1st question should be: how did you install it? (please add the answer to the question by editing it)

Comment: @Rinzwind I've updated my question with how I installed it.

Comment: see if my answer is sufficient @itsols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Removing Packages**

> To remove installed components, on the IDE menu, click Package > Configure installed packages. The following image shows the Installed Packages tool.

[image]

[Source](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Packages)

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have tried your method. You're on Windows so this is a little different. Anyway, despite removing the package my problem still persists. Nevertheless, you did answer the question. So thanks!

Comment: No windows here its a picture I found on the web ;)

Comment: Oh, BTW, I fixed the problem. The reports weren't working in another location because I hadn't put the reports source files (.lrf) to the destination path. I did not know that this was a requirement. The moment I put one, to test, it worked. Now I know the problem wasn't with the LazReport component. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Post it as a comment and accept yours :) and Ill remove this so others will have benefits from your experience!